# Azure AD B2C MFA and Trusted Devices

Tags: azure, multi-factor-authentication, azure-ad-b2c

Azure MFA documentation discusses a "trusted device" feature.  Specifically, the ability for a user to select "remember me on this device" when the log in with MFA to avoid MFA for a given period of time on the same device.

Is this feature available using MFA through Azure AD B2C?  If so, where is this documented?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, **Azure AD B2C's MFA feature does NOT support the ability to set a device as a "trusted device".**

You can request this feature in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](http://aka.ms/aadb2c).